# how to increase efficiency of invoke-command using session to collect logs from remote computer in powershell?

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

how to increase efficiency of invoke-command using session to collect logs from remote computer in powershell?Its taking 1min 51sec for collecting 98k no. of logs for me.

i measured the performance using the following code :

```
Measure-Command
{
    invoke-command -Credential $cred -cn $user -ScriptBlock
    {
        get-wmiobject -class win32_ntlogevent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you measured the performance of your script(s) to find out which part is the bottleneck? Post your code - it's impossible to give tuning assistance without knowing what has to be tuned.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment yet as I don't have enough reputation)

Would some of the other Event Log based cmdlets be useful here?

For example:

`Get-EventLog` (if using v2 or newer)
`Get-Event` (if using v1)
`Get-WinEvent`

Take a look at the output of `Get-Command *event*` for more options depending on what exactly you need to collect and what you need to do with it.

You could use the `Measure-Command` to see which returns the data faster.